# Dynamic Dropdown using semantic ui

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

Got a problem with semantic-ui dropdown. I've been using Semantic-Ui, and wanted to change the dropdown item dynamically. That is, when i choose the value from the first dropdown, the second dropdown's item is not getting reflected.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#programmetype").dropdown({
    onChange: function() {

      $('#servicetype').html(
        '<div class="ui selection dropdown select- 
        language ">'+'<div class="
        text ">Choose..</div>'+'<i class="
        dropdown icon "></i>'+' <div class="
        menu ">'+


        '<div class="item" data-value="acp">ACP</div>' +
        '<div class="item" data- 
        value = "art" > ART < /div>'+'</div > '+' < /div>'
      );
      $('#servicetype').dropdown();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>


<div id="programmetype" class="ui selection dropdown select- 
        language">
  <input type="hidden" name="programmetype">
  <div class="text">Choose..</div>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="val1">Car</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="val2">Tank</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="val3">Plane</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="servicetype"></div>
```

Comment: your code has syntax errors, inside your `.html()` method, your strings are not properly concatenated. check there and fix the inner content syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Syntax Errors

You are making line breaks inside your `string`s, break the lines properly with a `+` operator and your script won't find a syntax error, thus your code should run.

### Second Dropdown

About the second dropdown. you're missing something. Look at the first dropdown DOM structure. the parent element `#programmetype` has the classes `ui selection dropdown select-language` for the CSS to get applied.

But for your `#servicetype`, you don't have those classes and you never added them, so in the `onChange` of your first dropdown, add these classes, (check the script)

Also, you need a hidden `input` to hold the data which you missed. But it's there for the first dropdown. Check the snippet, I've added them.

Hope this helps.

Check the snippet bellow:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#programmetype").dropdown({
    onChange: function() {

      $('#servicetype').addClass('ui selection dropdown select-language'); // add these classes for the UI.
      $('#servicetype').html(
        '<input type="hidden" name="servicetype">' // you need a hidden input and the rest is fine
        +'<div class="text">Choose..</div>'
        +'<i class="dropdown icon "></i>'
        +'<div class="menu">'
        +'<div class="item" data-value="acp">ACP</div>'
        +'<div class="item" data-value="art"> ART</div>'
        +'</div>'
        +'</div>'
      );
      $('#servicetype').dropdown();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>


<div id="programmetype" class="ui selection dropdown select-language">
  <input type="hidden" name="programmetype">
  <div class="text">Choose..</div>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="val1">Car</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="val2">Tank</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="val3">Plane</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="servicetype"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Towkir,second dropdown is not opening

Comment: Could you please help me  on this

Comment: @TejashwiniShankar check now, the answer is edited, feel free to upvote the answer if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: the second dropdown is not opening could you please help me on this

Comment: I can see the second dropdown working fine on the above snippet. what is happening at yours ?

Comment: Hi Towkir ,i need third dropdown could you please help me whether I could add addId as addClass

Comment: Hi @TejashwiniShankar, since it's not ideal to add multiple `id` on the same element, you can't `.addId()` but you can set the `id` of an element where there is no `id` set, or change the current `id` with `.attr('id', 'yourIdValue')`

Comment: Hi @Towkir,Please find the below code.where the 3rd dropdown is not displaying ,could you please help me on this.